# How to use setState(){} properly in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, state-management

I have dropdown in my app. It's working fine, but whenever i'm selecting an item from drop down its reload the whole page and set the value. Why so? can't I set the value in my variable without reloading my screen using setState(){}?

```
String _selectedHeight = "4 ft";
  List<String> height = ["4 ft", "5 ft", "6 ft", "7 ft"];
```

then using this dropdown under my  FutureBuilder(){}:

```
        DropdownButton<String>(
          value:_selectedHeight,
          underline:Container(),
          icon: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down),
          iconSize: 24,
          isExpanded:true,
          items: height.map(( String height) =>DropdownMenuItem<String>(
          child:Text(height),
           value:height,
           )).toList(),
             onChanged:(val) {
                setState(() {
                   _selectedHeight = val!;
                });
               },
             ),
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could just use "=" operator. This changes the value of the variable without refreshing the state.

The use of "setstate" is to refresh/rerender the whole component to match the change, so we cannot set the value in a variable without reloading the screen using setState

Comment: where to use this operator`=` in setState(){}?.. I think I'm already using it. or correct me please if I'm wrong

Comment: onChanged:(val) {
                   _selectedHeight = val!;
               },

Comment: Like this. Don't enclose it within setstate

Comment: I understand.. Its not refreshing the page anymore but its also not setting the value in drop down.. its always `4` even i select a different value from drop down.

Comment: A few screenshots will help me understand your situation, like where it is unwantedly refreshing and where particularly do u want the value updated.

Comment: `https://gitlab.com/-/snippets/2232969` here is my whole class file.... (not just for the drop down , wherever i use setState(){} to change the value its refresh the page).. (adding screenshot shortly)

Comment: Hey, Thank you for your time.Can you look at this video for better understand..

Comment: try and check the "height" dropdownbutton like the example given here 

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/flutter-dropdownbutton-widget/#:~:text=DropDownButton%3A%20In%20Flutter%2C%20A%20DropDownButton,shows%20the%20currently%20selected%20value.